# How do you create a n by n box of X's in python using string manipulation? (eg. replace, count, find, len, etc.)

Tags: python

Get a number from the user (n) and create an n x n box of "X"es on the screen. Without using loops yet.
e.g. If they entered 12:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The point of this assignment is to use string manipulation to create this box.  I can do it with a loop but I'm not sure how to do it with just strings.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: yea it was and I got the answer from my super-genious friend.  Let's just say he re-made Mario and Pokemon in pygame just for fun.

Answer (score 4):

You can "multiply" strings. For example, `'x' * 3` gives you `xxx`. So:

```
size = int(input())  # convert whatever you have to int
print(size * (size * 'X' + '\n'))  # print the whole thing
```

This isn't very intuitive (very few languages will let you do that), but getting the input should be straightforward enough.

Comment: @MattBall I guess it depends on your background. As I said, very few languages will let you do that (the only other one I know is Ruby)

Comment: Yea I know I can multiply strings, the thing I was having trouble with is the new line.  I kept getting an error message.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You want to call `input`, and in 2.x it's `raw_input`. What was the difficulty with the newline BTW? (In the future, consider asking your question more specifically about the part that caused a problem for you.)

Comment: this is my third week with python... third week coding period actually.  I was missing something to do with the new line and I got an error message saying "unexpected character after line continuation"

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [join](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.join):

```
print('\n'.join(['X'*12]*12))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
size = int(raw_input())
print ('X' * size + '\n') * size,
```

In 3.x, that would be

```
size = int(input())
print(('X' * size + '\n') * size, end='')
```